# Raspberry Pi Python String not Defined

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, new-operator, raspbian

Hello I was working on a new python script today and I ran into this error.  Im a little confused about it, plus being new to scripting I dont know how to define this code.  Any help would be wonderful.  Thank you

Error

```
 File "newipemail.py", line 25, in <module>

    text = 'The IP address is: %s' % inet_string

NameError: name 'inet_string' is not defined
```

Script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import smtplib
import string
import time

FIXED_IP = '10.10.2.10'

ipaddr_string = 'ip -4 addr > ~/current_ip.txt'
subprocess.call(ipaddr_string, shell=True)

ip_file = file('current_ip.txt', 'r')
for line in ip_file:
        if 'eth0:' in line:
            inet_line = ip_file.next()
            _time = time.asctime()
            inet_string = inet_line[9:(inet_line.index('/'))]
            if inet_string != FIXED_IP:
                print 'Found eth0: %s' % inet_string

SUBJECT = 'IP Address from Raspberry Pi at: %s' % time.asctime()
TO = 'user@emial.com'
FROM = 'pi@email.com'
text = 'The IP address is: %s' % inet_string
BODY = string.join((
    'From: %s' % FROM,
   'To: %s' % TO,
    'Subject: %s' % SUBJECT,'',text), '\r\n')

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login('email.server.com', 'password')
server.sendmail(FROM, [TO], BODY)
server.quit()

ip_file.close()
```

Comment: are you sure that you have "eth0:" in your file current_ip.txt?

Comment: The variable `inet_string` is only defined if you find the *eth0:* in your file. The error indicate that the variable is not defined which means that the file probably doesn't contain *eth0:*

Comment: after the `inet_line = ip_file.next()` line, check what the value of inet_line is with `print(inet_line)`. This will give you the clue of why `inet_string` is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that for the current `line` in `current_ip.txt`, the string `eth0:` is not found. Because of this, your if-statement returns `False`.

```
if 'eth0:' in line:
    inet_line = ip_file.next()
    _time = time.asctime()
    inet_string = inet_line[9:(inet_line.index('/'))]
```

If `eth0:` is found in `line`, `inet_line` is defined, otherwise it will not be defined and Python jumps to the next code block which is where the exception is raised.

```
text = 'The IP address is: %s' % inet_string
```

Answer (score 0):

When I went into the file i had accidentally placed eth0 as eth1 I changed it back to eth0 and it worked great.

Comment: ok, I voted to close the question as you already found the problem and was due to a coding error